# While in x86-64 assembly

Tags: assembly

I am trying to create while with a assembler to it should simply check if m > n and give out a text or increase a num

```
section .data
        numb: db "Enter a number: "

section .bss

section .text

        global _start:
_start:
        mov rax, 4
        mov rbx, 1
        mov rcx, 5
        cmp rdx, 7
        ja
```

**EDIT**

```
section .data
        numb: db "Enter a number: "

section .bss

section .text

        global _start:
_start:
        mov rax, 4
        mov rbx, 1
        mov rcx, numb
        cmp rcx, 7
        ja
```

I use 64 bit registers. But I don't know how it is possible because an assembler don't have a while statement  so we have to use the cmp and jump above but now stuck here

Comment: You may think of a `while` loop as `begin: if (!condition) goto end; do_stuff; goto begin; end:`. Implementing that in assembly should be straight-forward. If you're unsure about what an instruction does, look it up in [Intel's Software Developer's Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html?iid=tech_vt_tech+64-32_manuals).

Comment: @Michael o you mean I can use the if statement in assembler?

Comment: No, you would use a conditional jump (probably preceded by a `cmp`) in x86 assembly. I was just showing the logic in a way that corresponds pretty closely to how you'd structure the assembly code.

Comment: @Michael I think its  cmp rax, rbx if cmp = True then do this....

Comment: @Michael hmm ok I will try it :)

Comment: @Michael  I have a beginning and add numbers to registers and compare  using cmp if it is less or  equal  if yes it should stop, but if it  its greater the then  it could start again our print out a message but  I get everytime  with every try a memory access error

Comment: Your second line has a label (numb:) that I wonder if you meant to be the name of the declared byte db "Enter a number: ".  Note the : after it.  I'm also wondering if it shouldn't be zero terminated.

Answer (score 0):

c++

```
int m = 10;
int n = 1;

while (m > n) {
  n++;
}
```

becomes

```
    mov rax, 10     ' m
    mov rbx, 1      ' n

start_loop:

    cmp rax, rbx    ' Compare m and n
    jle exit_loop   ' Conditional jump on <= which is the same as !>
    add rbx, 1      ' Body
    jmp start_loop  ' Unconditional jump

exit_loop:
```

Everything between the jumps is the while body.  The tricky bit is changing > to jle.  It's because we want to do the conditional jump when the while condition fails not when it passes.  So rather than > becoming jg it becomes jle.  It's so we jump when the while condition DIDN'T pass.

Comment: you explained it really well, now I understood how it really works but I get a memory access error

Comment: Exactly what line is giving you a memory access error?

Comment: there is  no line only a text printed out  that I gave a 'memory access error'

Comment: I remove a message that should printet out  if it is greater but after that I get the same error

Comment: Use your debugger to step thru one line at a time.  When the error shows up note which line you were on.  If that line isn't part of this loop you're going to have to open another question.

Comment: See my comment under the question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52474/discussion-between-candiedorange-and-kate)

Comment: Whats the difference in using `add rbx, 1` instead of `inc rbx`?

Answer (score 0):

There are two common patterns for while,

```
loopheader:
  some test
  jcc exit
  body
  jmp loopheader
exit:
```

which is the most obvious, and

```
  jmp loopentry
looptop:
  body
loopentry:
  some test
  jcc looptop
```

which has only one jump per iteration (both have only one *taken* jump per iteration though). It can be seen as a [loop inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_inversion) where the two conditions share the same code.